# How to pass file(Image) via NextJS API Routes to external API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I use NextJS (combined: SSR and SPA for authorized dashboard) with Django Rest FW on the backend. For auth I use JWT token, which is stored in cookies. For that reason, I need a middleware at /pages/api/* for each request to append from cookie access token.

Question:
How to implement a protected request to send file to /pages/api/upload and send it to DRF with an access token?

Sample of small API middleware

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.query
  const cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie ?? "");
  const access = cookies["access"] ?? false;
  if (access === false) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      error: "User unauthorized to make this request"
    });
  }

  if (req.method === "GET") {
    try {
      const apiRes = await fetch(`${LOCAL_API_URL}/items/${id}`, {
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${access}`
        }
      });
      const data = await apiRes.json();
      if (apiRes.status === 200) {
        return res.status(200).json(data);
      } else {
        return res.status(apiRes.status).json({
          error: data.error
        });
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: "Something went wrong"
      });
    }
  } else
    res.setHeader("Allow", ["GET"]);
  return res.status(405).json({
    error: `Method ${res.method} is not allowed`
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you use an [`express-jwt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) middleware (or similar) before your API middleware to validate the JWT? If so, the API middleware is already protected.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen no, I don't use Express at all, I use NextJS API Routes. Question is how to bypass file via API Routes

Comment: where exactly you are facing issue, unable to get cookies ? or file upload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution was raiser simple. Just passed everything I received and appended token to headers/

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  // all extra validation
  const apiRes = await fetch(`${LOCAL_API_URL}/upload/`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { ...req.headers, ...{ "Authorization": `Bearer ${access}` } },
    body: req.body
  });
  // all extra validation
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For sending image you should use FormData.
Firstly create an instance of FormData.

```
const formData = new FormData()
```

Then, you can add image into that.

```
formData.append('fieldName', someFileInput.current.files[0])
```

Also, if you want to add some more data with the image, you can append it to FormData too, the similar way.

```
formData.append('fieldName', someMoreData)
```

Then, you should set Content-Type to 'multipart/form-data', this is to server understand you pass the FormData.

And, finally, send the form data via Fetch.

I was glad to answer you, I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks, but the question is not about how to send the file, but how to pass it from nextjs API to external api